# Mulitple Search queries SharePoint 2013 page

Tags: search, document, library, scope

We have setup a SharePoint page that has 3 seperate search boxes, each of which need to each query 3 seperate document libraries.

Is it possible to do this and if so what process do we need to follow to do this?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

List View web parts in 2013 have the ability to be searched OOB through the web part properties. THere is a webpart property called "Display Search Box" that allows on the fly search of that list/library.

[image]

Comment: So I gather there is no way to use those larger search boxes I have inserted - you have to use the List View Web Part search field instead? Also is there any way to filter the list so that by default the contents dont load however items do load on search?